# Finding a 'hello' word in a different string, which it has 'hello' in it

Tags: python

I should find a 'hello' word in a string, which I gave it from input.
Here is the code that I currently have, but I cannot match 'hello' with the character list.

```
mylist = 'it can be any letter plus hello in it'
for letter in mylist:
    if letter in key:
        mylist2+=letter
print(mylist2)
mylist2 = ['h', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'o']
```

Comment: I've attempted to revise your title into a coherent question, but I suspect that it's not quite right. Feel free to revise again.

Comment: The description you put for your issue is hugely complex; please add as much clarification as possible to your question : for example: `helllloossaattt` this can results in `hell`, `hello`,`lost`,`sat`,`host`,`heat`, etc... etc... What are the expected answers?

Comment: I should track the first complex letter with the key of 'hello'. if I can find that exactly. the out put will be YES and on the other case NO.
for '''helllloossaattt ' : it has 'h' 'e' 'l' 'l' and 'o' so the output would be YES.

as I guess I should track the input word and try to remove extra letter. but I dont know how to track it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here is the code which I think that can find the 'hello' word in strings.

```
firststring = input() #ahhellllloou
to_find = "hello"

def check_string(firststring, to_find):
   c = 0
   for i in firststring:
       #print(i)
       if i == to_find[c]:
           c += 1
       if c == len(to_find):

           return "YES"
   return "NO"

print(check_string(firststring, to_find))
```

Answer (score -3):

```
x=input()
if x.find('h')!=-1:
    a=x.find('h')
    if x.find('e',a,len(x))!=-1:
        b=x.find('e',a,len(x))
        if x.find('l',b,len(x))!=-1:
            c=x.find('l',b,len(x))
            if x.find('l',c+1,len(x))!=-1:
                d=x.find('l',c+1,len(x))
                if x.find('o',d,len(x))!=-1:
                    print('yes')
                else:
                    print('no')
            else:
                print('no')
        else:
            print('no')
    else:
        print('no')            
else:
    print('no')
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.