# Finding a 'hello' word in a different string, which it has 'hello' in it(additional)

Tags: python, string, function

[Finding a 'hello' word in a different string, which it has 'hello' in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55518929/finding-a-hello-word-in-a-different-string-which-it-has-hello-in-it)
I should find a 'hello' word in a string, which I gave it from input too .I wrote this code by looking at the answer that someone gave to the below link's question.

```
firststring = input() #ahhellllloou
to_find = "hello"

def check_string(firststring, to_find):
   c = 0
   for i in firststring:
       #print(i)
       if i == to_find[c]:
           c += 1
       if c == len(to_find):
           return "YES"
   return "NO"

print(check_string(firststring, to_find))
```

but I don't want to use a `def` to solve the problem.

```
hello = "hello"
counter_hello = 0
bool_hello = False

for letter in string:
    if letter == hello[counter_hello]:
        counter_hello += 1
    if counter_hello == len(hello):
        bool_hello = True

if bool_hello == True:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

for `hello` string it works correct. also for `pnnepelqomhhheollvlo`.
but when I give it `ahhellllloou` it doesn't work.
I can't see where the bug is.

Comment: Please explain why you dont want to use functions

Comment: you forgot to reset the counter to 0 if you read a letter that is not in the word hello. That's why it matches helXXXXXXlo.

Comment: I'm new to python and some times I get in trouble with functions and of course I know I should struggle with it to learn. but I'm trying to learn the logic first and soon learn tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not the same. The return statement needs to be accounted for by breaking the loop

```
string = "ahhellllloou"
to_find = "hello"

match = False
c = 0
for i in string:
   if i == to_find[c]:
       c += 1
   if c == len(to_find):
       match = True
       break
print("YES" if match else "NO")
```

Note that a loop isn't needed

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search('.*'.join('hello'), 'ahhellllloou')
>>> m is not None
True
>>> m = re.search('.*'.join('hello'), 'ahhellllliu')
>>> m is None
True
```

Comment: thanks. I should learn to work with re library.

Answer (score 0):

```
counter_hello = 0
bool_hello = False

for letter in 'ahhellllloou':
    #print('letter: ', letter);
    #print(hello[counter_hello])
    if letter == hello[counter_hello] and counter_hello != len(hello) - 1:
        counter_hello += 1
    if counter_hello == len(hello) - 1:
        bool_hello = True

if bool_hello == True:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```